# How to deploy vsto excel solution so that administrator rights are not asked for both installation and usage?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2012, vsto

How to deploy vsto excel solution so that administrator rights are not asked for both installation and usage?

I am developing vsto solution on a computer where I am not administrator.
When I publish to setup.exe with InstallShield, then I can't run the exe
because it asks me for admin password. So I can't test my project now.
Is there a way around this so that I can install the project without being admin?
And then also I would like to run the excel workbook file without asking me for admin password.